# Adonis how to return only the result of the with method using the where

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I'm doing a query on a table in which there is a hasToMany relationship, when I use with and inside it I do the where to filter only the results I'm interested in, it isn't working, has anyone been there? it brings all the results, some keep the object key null and the other with the object, but what does not return in the where of the method with would not like to list

```
let projects = await Project.query()
    .with("share_info", (builder) => {
      builder.where("type", 2)
    })
    .fetch()
```

It's result

```
 [{
    id: 71,
    title: 'Strategy',
    owner_id: 2,
    publishing_id: null,
    full_path: 'sub20/teste/teste/brasil.jpeg',
    path_storage: 'sub20/teste/teste/brasil.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    size: 8428,
    checksum: 'string',
    metadata: 'string',
    created_at: '2021-05-03 17:28:24',
    project_modified_at: null,
    publishing_modified_at: null,
    updated_at: '2021-05-03 17:28:24',
    removed_at: null,
    share_info: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 72,
    title: 'Strategy',
    owner_id: 1,
    publishing_id: null,
    full_path: 'sub20/teste/teste/brasil.jpeg',
    path_storage: 'sub20/teste/teste/brasil.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    size: 8428,
    checksum: 'string',
    metadata: 'string',
    created_at: '2021-05-03 17:29:08',
    project_modified_at: null,
    publishing_modified_at: null,
    updated_at: '2021-05-03 17:29:08',
    removed_at: null,
    share_info: []
  },
  {
    id: 73,
    title: 'Strategy',
    owner_id: 1,
    publishing_id: null,
    full_path: 'sub20/teste/teste/brasil.jpeg',
    path_storage: 'sub20/teste/teste/brasil.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    size: 8428,
    checksum: 'string',
    metadata: 'string',
    created_at: '2021-05-05 21:13:14',
    project_modified_at: null,
    publishing_modified_at: null,
    updated_at: '2021-05-05 21:13:14',
    removed_at: null,
    share_info: []
  }]
```

As I am done where to list only type equal 2, the rest should not list as shown in the result that has objects with the empty share_info key

I'm using Adonis 4.1

Comment: Inside your call back try using this `builder.select().where("type", 2);`

Answer (score 0):

If the `share_info` relationship is needed in the results you could try this.

```js
let projects = await Project.query()
    .with("share_info")
    .whereHas("share_info", (builder) => {
      builder.where("type", 2);
    })
    .fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let projects = await Project.query()
    .select("share_info")
    .with("share_info", (builder) => {
      builder.where("type", 2)
    })
    .fetch()
```

Please try this